# How do I install openjfx on Ubuntu 14.04 / Linux Mint 17

Tags: 14.04, apt, java, openjdk, mint

It seems that attempts to backport OpenJFX (`libopenjfx-java`) to Ubuntu 14.04 / Linux Mint 17 have stalled (see bugs below).  This package is required by many projects using JDK 8, how can I install it on my system?

Related bugs:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1341628
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/trusty-backports/+bug/1368094

Answer (score 2):

Binaries are not available for these older systems, but you can compile from source:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libopenjfx-java
sudo apt-get --compile source libopenjfx-java
```

You can then install the packages by double clicking on each deb file to install:

```
libopenjfx-jni_8u60-b27-4~trusty1_amd64.deb
libopenjfx-java_8u60-b27-4~trusty1_all.deb
libopenjfx-java-doc_8u60-b27-4~trusty1_all.deb
openjfx_8u60-b27-4~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: In case the first command fails, make sure the line for `deb-src` in (typically) `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk-r-ppa-trusty.list` isn't commented out.

Comment: Step 1 fails: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (= 7:2.7.2-1dhor~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for libopenjfx-java could not be satisfied."

Comment: @didi_X8 thank you so much... also "sudo apt update" is important after your step...

Comment: I try runnign the fisrt command, after updating /etc/apt/sourceslist.d.... and get "Unable to find source package for libopenjfx-java"